# Data Augmentation causing test and validation sets to be smaller

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

I am dealing with an image dataset of 400, and split it into 70% train, 15%test, 15%validation. I would like to do some data augmentation (rotations/flips) to increase the amount of train data I have directly in tensor flow. I read that you typically only augment the training set. If I do this, my test and validation data would be much smaller than my train. Is that fine?
Also, just to provide some context, I plan to train an end-to-end cnn as a binary classifier.

I'm really new to machine learning, and would appreciate any advice!

Comment: Please help!!! I am high school student who has a deadline in 4 hours...